# Avro schema evolution in c#. Specify default value in datamember

Tags: c#, avro, confluent-platform

I am currently using the AvroDataContractResolver to serialise POCO from C# into schema registry. I'm trying to evolve the model to include an extra field that is an enum. The current model looks like below.

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Its schema

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "Person",
"namespace": "Core.Poco",
"fields": [
  {
    "name": "Name",
    "type": [
      "null",
      "string"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Age",
    "type": "int"
  }
]
}
```

When I add the enum Gender to the person POCO I will need to add a default value for the enum to make the schema backwards compatible. I am having a look through the code at https://github.com/welly87/Microsoft-Avro-Core and I dont see any way to specify a default value for the avro schema. Is there some way to specify a default value or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The avro specs https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html use the default keyword. Assuming Microsoft is following the specs.  Otherwise download the nuget package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/blachniet.Avro/ which dotnet core compatible fork https://github.com/blachniet/avro
e.g.

```
    {
"type": "record",
"name": "Person",
"namespace": "Core.Poco",
"fields": [
  {
    "name": "Name",
    "type": [
      "null",
      "string"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Age",
    "type": "int"
  },
    "name": "Gender",
    "type": "int",
    "default" : null,
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use avrogen:
https://github.com/ch-robinson/dotnet-avro

And decorate your class member with the DefaultValue attribute:

```
public class Person
{
   [DefaultValue("John Doe")]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public int Age { get; set; }

   [DefaultValue("MALE")]
   public GenderType Gender { get; set; }
}

public enum GenderType
{
    MALE,
    FEMALE
}
```

When you use avrogen to generate the schema, it will include the default value.